# What is the difference between -mno-thumb and GCC_THUMB_SUPPORT = NO

Tags: xcode, llvm, thumb

It seems there are two ways to turn off Thumb support in Xcode 4.5:

1. Specifying the `-mno-thumb` flag in `Build Settings/Other C Flags`
2. Setting `GCC_THUMB_SUPPORT` to `NO` in `Build Settings/User-Defined`

Is there a difference between these two methods?